# KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pickle, knn

I am trying to add new encodings and names to saved pickle file (KNNClassifier object) - but unable to append.

```
 # Save the trained KNN classifier
    if os.path.getsize(model_save_path) > 0:  
        if model_save_path is not None:
            with open(model_save_path, 'rb') as f:
                unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
                clf = unpickler.load()


        newEncodings = X, y
        clf.append(newEncodings)

        with open(model_save_path,'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(clf, f)
    
    else:
        if model_save_path is not None:
            with open(model_save_path, 'wb') as f:
                 pickle.dump(knn_clf, f)
```

Getting error:

```
'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to train it again from the new data ? if it is the case do clf.fit(X, y). Or do you want to train it more ? I thing you have to fetch original data and add the new one, to use the fit method on the whole data set.

Comment: I am trying to append new data with existing trained data

Answer (score 0):

According to what you want to do exaclty with the new data, you could:

train it again :

```
clf.fit(X, y)
```

or just do some predictions:

```
clf.predict(X)
```

If you need to train it with old and new data do:

```
clf.fit(Xold+X, yold+y)
```

Some classifiers have the following methods which could help you do incremental fitting to newly added data:

estimator.set_params(n_estimators=110, warm_start=True)

or

estimator.partial_fit(...)

KNeighborsClassifier seems to support the  warm_start=True parameter
so you should try:

```
clf.set_params(warm_start=True)
clf.fit(newX, newy)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Malo. How do I get old data from classifier object as it is already trained and saved as pickle file? I mean how to extract X and y from pickle file - I tried with items() dict, but did not work.

Comment: Some classifiers have the following methods which could help you do incremental fitting to newly added data:
estimator.set_params(n_estimators=110, warm_start=True)
or
estimator.partial_fit(...)

KNeighborsClassifier seems to support the  warm_start=True parameter
so you should try:

clf.set_params(warm_start=True)
clf.fit(newX, newy)

Comment: I am checking on that. When I use warm_start, what happens to previously trained data, will be able to perform inference on the old data, or will it override?

Comment: warm_start allows to fit a model with several batch of data, keeping old data. So this should work for you.